Weak convergence of degenerated random variable with finite support. Does it work?
This is what I learnt:

The requirement that only the continuity points of F should be considered is essential. For example, if Xn are distributed uniformly on intervals (0,
1
/
n
), then this sequence converges in distribution to the degenerate random variable X = 0. Indeed, Fn(x) = 0 for all n when x ≤ 0, and Fn(x) = 1 for all x ≥
1
/
n
when n > 0. However, for this limiting random variable F(0) = 1, even though Fn(0) = 0 for all n. Thus the convergence of cdfs fails at the point x = 0 where F is discontinuous.

Does this mean that the weak convergence does not work for degenerated r.v.?
A degenerated r.v. is a r.v. with finite support. In this question we only consider the set of r.v. $X:S\to [0,1]$ with finite supports.
Example: Say we have a sequence of Dirac distribution, $\delta_{1/n}$, does this sequence converge to $\delta_0$ in the topology of weak convergence?
If I use the same logics in the quoted paragraph, then, because $F_n(0)=0$ for all $n$, we must conclude that the convergence of cdfs fail!

For $x<0$, $F(x)=F_n(x)=0$.
For $x>0$ and $n$ large enough, $1/n<x$ so $F(x)=F_n(x)=1$.
So the convergence of cdfs holds on all continuity points of $F$.
